# Constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, bluej

So I am very new to Java... been at it for about 4 weeks... be gentle.

I am trying to get my takeItem method (below) to pass the itemName variable back to my Player Class so I can add an item from my current room to my player. I get the compiler error: Constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types..

my end goal is to get the player class to hold the object after removing it from the room.

takeItem Method:

```
private void takeItem(Command command) 
{

    if(!command.hasSecondWord()) {
        // if there is no second word, we don't know where to go...
        System.out.println("Take what?");
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }

    String itemName = command.getSecondWord();
    Item theItem;
    // Try to take an item.
    theItem = new Item(player.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemName));


    if (theItem == null) 
    {
        System.out.println("There is no item!");
    }
    else 
    { 
        player.addItem(theItem);
        player.getItemsCarried();//print item info
    }
```

Player Class:

```
//above code omitted//
public void setCurrentRoom(Room room)
{
 currentRoom = room;
}

public Room getCurrentRoom()
{
 return currentRoom;
}

//code below omitted//


 public void addItem (Item thingy)
 {

     items.put(thingy.getName(), thingy);

 }

  //code below omitted//
```

Item Class:

```
public class Item
{
  // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private int weight;

   /**
  * Constructor for objects of class Item
  */
  public Item(String n, String d, int w)
  {
  name = n;
  description = d;
  weight = w;
  }
 //code below omitted//
```

Room Class:

```
public class Room 
{
private String description;
private HashMap <String, Room> exits;
private HashMap <String, Item> items;
//some code below omitted//


 public Room (String description) 
 {
    this.description = description;
    exits = new HashMap<>();
    items = new HashMap<>();
  }


public void addItem (Item thingy)
{
    items.put(thingy.getName(), thingy);
}

public String removeItem(String thingy)
{
    items.remove(thingy);
    return thingy;

}
//code below omitted
```

Comment: where is your `Item` class, post its constructor/s.

Comment: Item Class: 
    public class Item
    {
     // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
     private String name;
     private String description;
     private int weight;

    
      public Item(String n, String d, int w)
      {
      name = n;
      description = d;
      weight = w;
      }

      public String getName()
     {
     return name;    
     }
  
      public String getDescription()
     {
       return description;    
     }
  
      public int getWeight()
      {
       return weight;    
      }
     }

Comment: Does `player.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemName)` return the item that is removed? If so, the line should be `theItem = player.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemName);` As you currently have it, you are attempting to create a new `Item` object where you pass whatever is returned by `player.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemName)` into the constructor.

Comment: @EyedJellyFish,
if I change the line you suggested
theItem = (player.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemName));

I get the following compiler error:

Incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Item

Comment: @Evan show us the code for the removeItem method.

Comment: @EyedJellyfish see the Room Class (added)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have a [mcve] instead of all of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor in the `Item` class takes two `String` parameters and one `int`, but you are trying to create a new `Item` by passing in only one `String` (whatever is returned by the `removeItem()` method). You can either change the `removeItem()` method so that it returns the `Item` that is removed, in which case you should change

`theItem = new Item(player.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemName));`

to

`theItem = player.getCurrentRoom().removeItem(itemName);`

or you can create a new `Item` with the necessary parameters.

Comment: Thanks Jelly,
I tried that, but the compiler error I get is  Incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Item

Comment: @Evan again, you need to change the removeItem method to return the `Item` that is removed. You can't simply assign a `String` to an `Item`.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I'm a noob/dummy